# How do I exclude the root directory from filepath.walkDir()?

Tags: go

```
func getDirs(root_dir string) []string {
    var dirs []string

    err := filepath.WalkDir(root_dir, func(path string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
        if d.IsDir() {
            dirs = append(dirs, filepath.Base(path))
        }
        return nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("error walking path %q: %v", root_dir, err))
    }
    return dirs
}
```

```
func TestGetDirs(t *testing.T) {
    got := getDirs("testdata/root_files")
    want := []string{"bar", "baz", "foo"}

    if reflect.DeepEqual(got, want) == false {
        t.Errorf("got %q want %q", got, want)
    }
}
```

```
testdata/
└── root_files
    ├── bar
    │   └── ping.txt
    ├── baz
    │   └── world.txt
    └── foo
        └── hello.txt

got ["root_files" "bar" "baz" "foo"] want ["bar" "baz" "foo"]
```

How do I exclude the first, root dir from the result? Is there some other built-in function I should be using?

Before returning results, removing the first item from slice seems like a hack. Is there a way to tell `filepath.WalkDir()` to exclude the root?

Comment: Add this line to the start of the function: `if path == root_dir { return nil }`

Comment: That'd be worse than removing first from slice, as it'd check every directory against it.

Comment: I think `removing the first item from slice` is not a hack, the root  dir should always the first item in this case.

Comment: The string comparison has a negligible impact on the performance of the walk.  A single string comparison is noise compared to everything else that happens in walk.

Comment: As per WalkFunc's documentation, the path argument may be cleaned. I think (I haven't tested it) that this might apply to the root dir too so you should take this into account if you go for the "comparing names" solution.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at other alternatives. `ioutil.ReadDir()` exists, but it'd be redundant to get results from there, and then loop over them.

After some other thinking, per @emptyhua's suggestion, my thought of popping the first item from the array seems to be fine.

```
    }
    return dirs
```

to

```
    }

    dirs = dirs[1:] // 0th item would otherwise be root_dir
    return dirs
```

This has the downside, that the listing has to complete fully before anything is returned.

Comment: you could also have a `var rootEncountered bool` outside your `WalkDir` loop which is turned to `true` on first valid condition. NB: This, however, is introducing an extra check for each loop iteration.